# Second tag replaces the first tag

Tags: support, tags, tag-autocomplete

I've just posted a question on Server Fault about Windows Profiles.

I started typing in "windows" in the tags and "windows" appeared on the drop down list.

> tags: windows

I then moved my cursor to the end and started typing "profile" as a "windows" tag on its own is pretty useless.

> tags: windows profile

However, on selecting "Profile" from the drop down list, "Windows" is removed and tag says "Profiles Pro".

> tags: profiles pro

I'm confused, how to I tag like the following?

> windows profile

Comment: Sounds like that's your problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14450/tag-suggestion-inserts-new-tags-at-wrong-position-on-ie6-and-ie7

Comment: Hey thanks, that edit helps clears things up a lot.

Comment: So a bug in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with your browser, which could be either IE6, IE7 or the stand out Opera.

Basically, the [tag suggestion is overwriting your first tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14450/tag-suggestion-inserts-new-tags-at-wrong-position-on-ie6-and-ie7), preventing you from easily making use of it as it just replaces it.

To tag your question, you have two options:

1. Tag it fast and ignore the suggestions
2. Type up the tags elsewhere and put them in later.

Comment: When it stands out, why does it have the same issue? :]

Comment: @John: because its supposed to be better?

Comment: "Opera is like the honors student who occasionally snaps and goes on a random killing spree. I'll take IE6 "special needs" over that any day" http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/3290996474