# Tags Moving Around on Edit

Tags: bug, tags, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Second tag replaces the first tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29212/second-tag-replaces-the-first-tag)

When I try to select a suggested tag with the mouse, it replaces the first tag in the tags list.

Comment: Please indicate the browser and OS so others can attempt to duplicate the issue.

Comment: Dupe, and known browsers are **Opera**, IE6 and IE7.